# Is it possible to auto-update the dependecy graph in VS2010 after changed made in the project?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, architecture, dependencies

The [Dependency Graph](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jennifer/archive/2010/05/11/visual-studio-2010-how-to-understand-your-code-using-dependency-graphs-sequence-diagrams-and-the-architecture-explorer.aspx) is a really great feature included in VS2010.

When I create a dependecy graph, is it possible to update it when I change the code in my solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is like a snapshot of your code at the time you generate it. To refresh, you must generate a new one.